# Scope of the extra properties in Gradle?

Tags: properties, gradle, build

I have a Gradle script similar to this:

```
ext {
  dir = null
}

task init << {
  build()
}

task buildAll(type: Exec){
  workingDir ext.dir
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "echo %JAVA_HOME%"
}

def build(){
  ext.dir = "asdf"
  buildAll.execute()
}
```

When I run the script, I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Cannot get property 'dir' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

Whatever I tried, I couldn't get a task to read a property from "ext". It can be seen from methods (like "build()" in my example), but not from any other task except the default one ("init" in my example).

I understand that the "ext" properties should be accessible from anywhere inside the project, so what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
The workflow I'm trying to achieve (as asked by Opal):

I have several environments I need to build with one script. Each of these environments is listed in a CSV file with a line: `<environment>,<version>`.

Script then needs to do the following:

- Delete existing directory
- Checkout code from SVN into new directory (both directory and SVN url depend on environment and version)
- Copy some settings files (paths depend on version)
- Edit some of those settings files (values depend on environment and version)
- Set some environment variables (JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME...) (depends on version)
- Run three build commands (`${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant -f $checkedOutCodeDirectory/Build/build-all.xml target1`, then `target2` and `target3`)

This needs to be executed for each environment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extra properties should be created via `ext` but referred via `project` instance without any instance at all so: `project.dir` or `dir`, so the first change to script will be:

```
ext {
  dir = null
}

task init << {
  build()
}

task buildAll(type: Exec){
  workingDir dir // ext.dir -> dir
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "echo %JAVA_HOME%"
}

def build(){
  ext.dir = "asdf"
  buildAll.execute()
}
```

Now, before any task or method is executed the script is read and parsed, sot the whole body of `buildAll` will be configured *before* any other part is *run*. Thus it will always fail, since `dir` property has no value. Proof:

```
ext {
  dir = null
}

task init << {
  build()
}

task buildAll(type: Exec){
  workingDir dir ? dir : project.rootDir 
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "echo %JAVA_HOME%"
}

def build(){
  ext.dir = "asdf"
  buildAll.execute()
}
```

Comment: That is exactly why I wonder how extra properties should be used. Basically, I want a global variable. How do I get a global variable in Gradle (deprecated solutions, used before extra properties were introduced, should not be considered)?

Comment: So define it in `ext` block and if there's a need to overwrite it pass it with `-P` command line switch.

Comment: I already defined it in ext. In order to get the path to the directory ("dir" variable), I need two other variables that I pass using -P, and that is why I can't use "dir" as a parameter to the build script. Oh, well...

Comment: @zorglub76, could you please prepare a real world example? If I understand the problem I my help you better.

Comment: Ok, I updated the original question with the workflow that I'm trying to automate. I'm new to Gradle, and wanted to make the script as Gradle-ly as possible, but at one point I found myself doing almost everything in Groovy, instead of using Gradle features, because of unexpected (seemingly) lack of Gradle features...

Comment: @zorglub76 It seems that what you need is not global properties but rather task rules: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F07. One rule for single environment. Moreover, using ant from gradle is possible however in your case it seems to be overkill. What don't you switch to gradle fully?

Comment: I've started working on this project 3 months ago, and the project itself is 20 years old. Build depends on bash, ant gradle and groovy scripts, so it's bit of a mess at the moment... Anyway, you mean that I should dynamically create all tasks and use rules to execute them?

Comment: Yes, for now it seems the best option. It would be nice to work on such project. I like tidying things up ;]

Comment: @zorglub76, if my answer helped you please accept or even upvote.